# Python tuple of tuple: access like a 2 dymentional array

Tags: python, windows, tuples

I have data that comes is as strings. I have a for loop to catch all data and put into a tuple. The reason I used a tuple was, I wanted to be able to access data like this,

```
tupOfTuple[1][0:4]#accessing x=1(line 1), elements 0-4.
```

Here is my current code,

```
while (deltaT < 80):
    deltaT = time() - start_time
    buf = create_string_buffer("\x22\x0F\x61", 77)
    res = ldv_read( handle, buf, len(buf))
    dataStr = [""]
    colTup = ()

    if (res == 0):
        print "\n"
        resZeroCount = resZeroCount + 1
        for c in buf.raw:
            dataStr = hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2),
            #Figure out the data type, for debug
            #print type(dataStr)
            colTup = colTup + dataStr
        print 'adding the lines with data into a another tuple' 
        rowTup = rowTup + colTup

print 'final tuple, this is a tuple of tuples'
for item in rowTup:
        print item,


print 'line 3 is, element 0'
print rowTup[3][0]
```

At the line that says "print rowTup[1][0]", I am getting following error,

```
"IndexError: tuple index out of range".
```

my rowTup should look like this,

```
18 23 43 srgrsdg 23 23 sdrfg
fd we 32 fgsfs   23 34 12
```

So for `rowTup[1][0]`, I was expecting to see `"fd"`. This is on Win7. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Should I try to use a 2 dimensional array instead?

Comment: Why are you using Tuples?  You're constantly "appending" data to these tuples by overwriting them with new tuples.  The immutability is completely contrary to what you want.

Comment: What should I use? I am a C++ programmer, not good at Python. If I were to do this in C++, I would use a 2 dimensional dynamic array. What is the best data structure for this in Python?

Comment: A tuple as a non-editable array.  It's more lightweight than an array, since all the functions associated with changing it aren't there.  It's great for handling things like function returns.  Not that practical for what you want to do with it, though.  I'd use a list instead.

Comment: Like I said, in C++ I would have done a 2 dimensional array. So I can access elements like myArray[5][4]. If I use a list, I can not access data like that, can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dataStr` is a tuple, you can do it by

```
colTup = colTup + (dataStr,)
```

Answer (score 1):

> colTup = colTup + dataStr
>   [...]
>   rowTup = rowTup + colTup

When you add two tuples together, it merges them, it doesn't create a tuple of tuples.  If rowTup was (1, 2, 3) and colTup was (4, 5, 6), then adding them together as you did would make a single new tuple with value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), and overwrites rowTup with this new tuple.

Because of how you're adding this content together, all you have is one giant tuple of items, NOT something multidimensional (also why you're getting the out of range error).

You could fix this and continue using tuples by adding them together as individual tuples: `rowTup = (rowTup,) + (colTup,)`. But let's discard tuples all together.  You're using them for something much better suited to lists (primarily, data that needs to change).

With lists, the functionality you want is significantly easier to obtain using the append option.  It's behaviour is:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a.append(2)
>>> print(a)
[1, 2]
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(3)
>>> b.append(4)
>>> print(b)
[3, 4]
>>> c = []
>>> c.append(a)
>>> c.append(b)
>>> print(c)
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

And, there you have a multidimensional list.  Accessing `c[0]` returns `[1, 2]`, and continuing that, `c[0][0]` returns `1`.

Comment: This is a better answer. For now, I think I am going to keep it tuples. Reason is, once I loaded my tuple with data, I don't want anyone to be able to change it. Plus ctypes returns a tuple for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that kind of indexing bussines, but you would want to do it with lists instead. This is because tuples are immutable (cannot be changed), and thus you actually copy over all previous values when you write something like

```
rowTup = rowTup + colTup
```

Don't do that. With lists, you can add entries by

```
a = []
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
```

resulting in a list [1,2].

As to why it goes out of range can, as I can see it, only be because one of the loops doesn't go to 3 (or 0 for that matter) prior to trying to execute rowTup[0][3].

EDIT: Also. as a minor thing, some of your print statements should be comments. You should use them this way

```
# This is a comment for the coder (ie. yourself).
# Variable a is here set and printed.
a = 2
print "Hello program user. This is a message for you. a =", a
```

EDIT2: You can easily view the contents of the tuple in Python. Simply write

```
print rowTup
```

Comment: If I were to use a list, I am not able to access element 5 like this, right? print myList[5]? Lie I said, in C++ I would have done a 2 dimensional array. So I can access elements like myArray[5][4]. If I use a list, I can not access data like that, can I?

Comment: List and tuples both has defined __getitem__ method. You can write "a = [[0,1],[2,3]]" and then "print a[1]" returning [2,3] or "print a[1][0]" returning 3. I think it's fastest to get familiar with python syntax using the interpreter. I usually have it open on the side to check syntax right away if needed. A little suggestion :)

Comment: @usustarr - A two-dimensional in Python array is just a list of lists (no different than C++).  Open up an interpreter and try `my_list = [[0, 1, 2,], [3, 4, 5,], [6, 7, 8,]]`, then `print(my_list[2][2])`.

Comment: @Dith - I do the exact same thing.  Half the time, I'm using it to see what exception will pop up if I do X...